# How do I pass parameter to controller action from jquery code in Grails using below code

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

I have a below code sample. I want to pass a parameter when making AJAX call to my controller using below code.

```
$('#testitemscat1').click(function() {
    $('#adthumbnails').load(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

I know we can use jQuery, but can we achieve using above code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#testitemscat1').click(function() {
    $('#adthumbnails').load(this.href, { myname: lukupname}, function(){
        // load success code
    });
    return false;
});
```